# Horizontal scroll works on IE11 but not on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to nest two flexboxes like this:

First one has two items: a button and a div, the div filling remaining space.

The div is also a flexbox with 3 items: 2 buttons (a left and a right) and a middle div which is scrollable

https://jsfiddle.net/mLtwmc62/

```css
.flex-container
{
   display: flex;
}

.flex-item-auto
{
     flex: 0 0 auto;  /* grow shrink basis */
}

.flex-item-fill
{
    flex: 1 1 auto;  
}

.middle
{
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}


.big
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <button class="flex-item-auto">View All</button>
    <div class="flex-item-fill flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item-auto">Prev</div>
        <div class="middle flex-item-fill">
            <div class="big"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item-auto">Next</div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

On IE11, it works as expected, I can see the right button and I can scroll the div.

But not on latest Chrome and Firefox, here the whole page is scrollable, not just the div.

I also need to make it work on mobile (Safari 8, Android 4.3+)

Comment: which container? also, is there any other way, I don't want to use fixed sizes or coordinates (that's the reason I'm using flex-boxes anyway) ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css like below. You need to set the width to 0 (see note below) on the fill elements.

And don't forget to prefix the "flex" properties for cross browser compatibility on older browser versions

Flex support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```css
.flex-container
{
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
}

.flex-item-auto
{
     -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;  /* grow shrink basis */
     flex: 0 0 auto;  /* grow shrink basis */
}

.flex-item-fill
{
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 0;
}

.left
{
    align-self:  -webkit-flex-start; /* align top */
    align-self:  flex-start; /* align top */
}

.middle
{
    background-color: green;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}

.next, .prev
{
    background-color: white;
}

.big
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <button class="left flex-item-auto">My Button</button>
    <div class="flex-item-fill flex-container">
        <div class="prev flex-item-auto">Prev</div>
        <div class="middle flex-item-fill">
           <div class="big"></div>
        </div>        
        <div class="next flex-item-auto">Next</div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:

> Obviously you would prefer to make a liquid layout rather than use px, but Firefox ignores child widths in percentages (ever wonder why whole page flexbox demos are all px?). Oh crap. The workaround is to use width: 0 and let box-flex dictate things.

Src: http://oli.jp/2011/css3-flexbox/

Comment: thanks. I don't want to use fixed sizes or coordinates (that's the reason I'm using flex-boxes anyway), isn't there really other way?

Comment: it doesn't work, the page gets a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: usually, 100% isn't necessary as these are block elements which fill the space

Comment: looks like if I set  .flex-item-fill {  flex: 1 1 0;  } it works on Chrome and IE but not on Firefox. See https://jsfiddle.net/xLtuo305/

Comment: @MikeFills Updated .. does it work now how you want?

Comment: thanks. it looks like it's working on desktop browsers but not on Safari on iOS 8

Comment: @MikeFills Updated my sample ... iOS/Safari and iOS/Chrome need the prefix "-webkit-" for flex to work.

Comment: Wow. Very nice. I forgot about the prefixes, thought it's not needed anymore in latest web-browsers, even if it's mobile. Can I ask what's the logic behind width: 0 ? I guess it means setting the initial width to 0 pixels?

Comment: but it's interesting that the div even with width: 0 is rendered nicely

Comment: thanks again. would be great if you could find the article. is it this one https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570036

Comment: @MikeFills Updated my answer with info and a link about the `width: 0` issue

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

You simply need to add `min-width: 0` to the parent of the scrolling item.

Instead of this:

```
.flex-item-fill {
    flex: 1 1 auto;  
}
```

Try this:

```
.flex-item-fill {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width: 0;    /* NEW */ 
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mLtwmc62/19/)

For an explanation see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982902/3597276

---

**Original Answer**

<s>This appears to be a bug in Firefox.</s>

If you make a slight adjustment to `.flex-item-fill`, the layout will work in IE11 and Chrome:

```
.flex-item-fill
{
   flex: 1; /* changed from `flex: 1 1 auto;` */
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mLtwmc62/14/

A similar bug was filed with Mozilla a few years ago. Referring to the link below, if you scroll down to the last comments, you'll see it's a problem that may still exist today, and it offers a hint toward a possible workaround.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570036

Comment: thanks, but your fiddle it's not working in Firefox, I have latest (v41.0.1)

Comment: It's not supposed to work in FF. Like I said in my answer, it works in IE and Chrome, but not FF, possibly due to a bug.

Comment: I've revised my answer with a precise solution. I've also linked to another answer with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to flex spec update: 
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto

Basically according to the new spec, min-width of the flex-item-fill is its min content.
The work around is explicitly setting min-width of flex-item-fill to 0px.
Or setting width to 0px as LGSon did.

Seems like Chrome does not support this new behavior yet.

Comment: Thank you. The workaround by setting width: 0 works in Chrome, not sure what you meant.