# Rendering problems using flexbox in Firefox and Chrome 48

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

**On chrome 47 (correct behavior):**
On chrome 47, that div with `.scroll` is scrolling correctly, taking height 100% using flex.

**On firefox (wrong behavior):**
While on firefox, that div with `.scroll` is using the content height and not scrolling properly.

What is the cross-browser solution to this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/d4nkevee/

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  $(".scroll").append("Dynamic content<br>");
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.scroll {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="bar">Small</div>
  
  <div class="content">
    
    <div>Static content</div>
    <div class="scroll"></div>
    <div>Static content</div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">Small</div>
  
</div>
```

---

**Question updated** to distinguish between Chrome 47 and Chrome 48.

Comment: The standard behavior is Firefox's one. And latest Chromium behaves like that too.

Comment: Thank you for saying that! Considering it is a duplicate, should I remove this question? @Oriol

Comment: Duplicate just means the question is closed to new answers. It's still good to keep for search purposes, as it may contain keywords not present in the dupe.

Comment: @Richard Duplicates are not always bad, they can help other people to find the other question. In this case I think you couldn't remove it even if you wanted, because it has an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The flexbox specification was updated making the default minimum size of flex items equal to the size of the content: `min-width: auto` / `min-height: auto`.

You can override this setting with `min-width: 0` / `min-height: 0`:

```
.content {
    background: yellow;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    min-height: 0;           /* NEW */
    min-width: 0;            /* NEW */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4nkevee/1/

Bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520

Here are some details from the spec:

> [**4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of
>   the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1. ([read more](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto))

---

**UPDATE**

It appears that Chrome has updated their rendering behavior. Chrome 48 now emulates Firefox in terms of minimum flex sizing.

Based on reports in the following links, the solution above should work in Chrome 48, as well.

- [Possible Chrome 48 flexbox bug causing layout issues. #6841](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6841)
- [Issue 580196: Nested 'flex-direction:column' elements don't shrink properly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580196)

Comment: I knew that this community would help me to fix this unexplained bug. Thank you very much. It worked here like a charm!

Comment: @Michael_B Out of curiosity, how does one go about finding a bug like this? Did you see it before this question? Create ten JSFiddles until you find the cause? Bribe a fortuneteller?

Comment: @LeonAdler, searching deep in google using various keywords then, if necessary, following the links in the pages you find, until you end up at your destination (if it even exists). Be a human web crawler ;-)

Comment: I was having this issue with Chrome 48.0.2564.103 on Mac. With this workaround, it's gone. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar situation where adding `min-height: 0` on children only partially solved the problem. After digging around, I found that mix of `min-height: 0` and `max-height: 100%` on children of a column-flexed container solves the firefox bug completely.