# Can flexbox children have overflow scrollbar(s)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to use the [CSS3 flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) to create a cross-device layout and found [a nice example layout by HugoGiraudel](http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/qIAwr) which I used as a starting point.

The layout basically looks like this:

[image]

Here is the structure of the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    ...
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Here the most important parts of the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
.aside { flex: 1 auto; }
.main    { flex: 3 0px; }
```

My problem is when the article contains more content than fits on the screen, a vertical scrollbar appears next to the outer `.wrapper` and the footer isn't visible any more.

[I tried to add `overflow: scroll` and `flex-flow: column wrap` to the article's styling](http://codepen.io/friendfx/pen/bEaXma), but without success - the scrollbars are visible but the article always grows to completely enclose its contents.

How can I keep the footer visible and the article scrolling if the contents grow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your article content expands the whole layout is that it doesn't have any height limitation. Something like `max-height` would limit its growth, and then a vertical scrollbar could appear.

Here's your code with a few adjustments:

**HTML** (added a nested flex container for article and asides)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <section class="inner-wrapper">
    <article class="main">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
         fames ac turpis egestas...</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
         fames ac turpis egestas...</p>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
         fames ac turpis egestas...</p>
                            .
                            .
                            .
    </article>
    <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
    <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS** (key adjustments only)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;        /* switch main container from row direction */
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;                 /* nested flex container; row direction */
  flex: 0 0 50%;                 /* limit height of container; adjust as necessary */
  min-height: 0;                 /* addresses a scrolling bug in Firefox;
                                    http://stackoverflow.com/a/34982902/3597276 */
}

.header {
    flex: 1;                     /* header to occupy all available height */
}

.footer {
  flex: 1;                       /* footer to occupy all available height */
}

.main {
  overflow-y: scroll;            /* enable vertical scrollbar */
}
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGeybW)

NOTES:

- Now the main flex container (`.wrapper`) has three flex items stacked vertically.
- The height of each item can be set individually. In the code above, the header and footer are told to consume all available space (`flex: 1`). The middle flex item (`.inner-wrapper`)  is confined to 50%, which enables scrolling. Try 25% and 75% for alternative examples.
- The middle item doubles as a flex container, and lines up the article and asides horizontally. The width of each item can be set individually. The previous point applies here, as well.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. For anyone looking for *minimum* sized header and footer, I changed the `.inner-wrapper` rule to `flex: 1 1` and removed the `flex` properties from both `.header` and `.footer` rules. A pen including this is [here](http://codepen.io/friendfx/pen/obdWoj).

Comment: Cool adjustment. The minimum sized header and footer makes sense.