# Flexbox and vertical scroll in a full-height app gives a second scroll bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning how to use flexbox and I've been reading quite a bit before trying it on my own.

I have a current issue with vertical scroll and flexbox that is very similar to this issue :

[Flexbox and vertical scroll in a full-height app using NEWER flexbox api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962468/flexbox-and-vertical-scroll-in-a-full-height-app-using-newer-flexbox-api)

But for a reason that I cannot figure out at the moment, the more my scrollable element expands, the bigger the total flexbox element is, which  shouldn't be the case.

Here is my example : https://jsfiddle.net/Munsta0/8afLpp0h/4/

```
#contentContainer {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 auto; //Rest of space
  overflow-y: scroll

  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content{
  min-height: -webkit-min-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

How can I prevent the whole thing to expand while I have an overflow-y: scroll?

**Edit**: I can confirm that this bug is only since chrome 48

Comment: So you want the red section to remain a fixed size? I'm not seeing a second scrollbar in Chrome or FF.

Comment: Using chrome latest version I see a double scrollbar on two different computer, I even tried incognito to make sure it wasn't something funky with an extension. I'm confused as to why you can't see it.

Comment: Try this maybe. It's a Firefox bug, but I've seen some comments lately saying it applies to newest Chrome, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34982902/3597276

Comment: It didn't solve it. On the other hand, my home pc was still with chrome 47 so I loaded up the fiddle and it was okay. Updated to 48 and now double bar. Well I guess I found the root of my problem at least

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be a Chrome 48 issue growing. It's apparently breaking a lot of production layouts. I updated my other answer with a couple of bug reports. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34982902/3597276