# CSS Flex box. height and Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

header {
  flex: 1;
  height: 60px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header p {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  height: 100%;
}



.right-pane {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #76DAFF;
}

.right-head {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #DDCA7E;
}

.right-body {
  background-color: #B9F;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <p>I am a fixed header</p>
  </header>
  <div class="main-wrap">
   
    <div class="right-pane">
      <div class="right-head">
        <p>I am a fixed container</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-body">
        <ul>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          <li>Scroll me I am famous!</li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This snippet works as expected on safari9 and Chrome but ffox fails.
I am trying not to have the main scrollbar showing on the page.

It looks like the height 100% takes the first header into account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: True, `min-height: 0;` did solve it on `.main-wrap`. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Used `min-heigh` on the scroll parent.

```
.main-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 0 auto;

  height: 100%;
}
```

As [Rendering problems using flexbox in Firefox and Chrome 48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982834/rendering-problems-using-flexbox-in-firefox-and-chrome-48)

Comment: Hm. Answering your own question which is a duplicate.....

Comment: There are several ways of exposing a same problem.