# Using flexbox and overflow hidden & scroll not working in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, overflow, flexbox

I have a relatively simple skeleton for a 1-page site.
The header area I'd like to stay put which I accomplished (at least in Chrome and my smartphone's native browser) by setting `overflow:hidden` on the overall container, then setting `overflow:scroll` to the scrollable area.

But then I went to double check this on FireFox and basically ran into all sorts of issues. Troubleshooting resulted in a mind-numbing amount of things falling out of place.

```
    <div id="mainBlock">

        <div id="tabContent">
            <div id="one">
                <h1>one</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="two">
                <h1>two</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="three">
                <h1>three</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="four">
                <h1>four</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bottomBlock">
            <div>hellow</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

with these styling rules

```
#mainBlock {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#tabContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#tabContent > *{
    height: 500px;
}
#bottomBlock {
    background-color: #444;
    height: 24px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When working, this results in the head area staying put while allowing for the rest of the content to scroll, with `bottomBlock` appearing at the end of the scrollable area.
However, in firefox, while scrolling is possible `bottomBlock` is stuck at end of initial viewport. As in if the viewport height is 900px, `bottomBlock` is seemingly absolute positioned at 901px.

If I move `bottomBlock` to within `tabContent`, then it works as it should.
But this issue has given me far too great of a headache to simply let it go.

I'm not sure how to make a fiddle of this, since the scroll bar is the main issue here, and fiddle's render box also has one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34982834/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in firefox 45.0.1 if you remove the `height:100%` from `#tabContent` completely. What do you need it for? As the last block element `#bottomBlock` will always be on the very bottom.
Maybe it's a wierd css overriding/priority issue. I could imagine FF can't calculate the overall content height correctly because of the competetive `#tabContent > *` and `#bottomBlock` selectors.

Did you also try making tabContent as a class? Sometimes that solves strange css inherit or override problems (for me).

Comment: It was for 'pushing' `bottomBlock` to .. well, the bottom in the case(s) where `tabContent` didn't have enough to take up a full page. But there are other ways to do this of course. Chrome I understand, but weird that my Android phone's 2014 stock browser has no issues rendering it haha. Thanks though!!