# Flexbox with a scrollable panel

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a layout that stretches to fill the screen, but then scrolls when the content is larger than the available pane.

I have a basic `flexbox` approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/3063706), and it does a good job filling up the screen, but overflowing content causes the whole screen to scroll rather than just its own container.

If I change `.outer` height to a literal value like `200px` then I get the scrolling behavior that I want, but the bottom content pane no longer fills up the screen.

I have tried using `display: table` and related CSS rather than flexbox, but ended up with the same result.

I have also considered using `calc` on the height of the content pane - something like

```
height: calc(100% - 60px);
```

but I want the header to be able to grow with its content, so I don't have a hard value for its height for the calculation.

I am looking for a pure CSS solution here rather than window sizing with Javascript of some flavor.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.box .row.header {
  background: aliceblue;
}
.box .row.content {
  background: pink;
}
.box .row.content .title {
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
.outer {
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.text {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="title">
      <b>content</b>
      (fills remaining space)
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
      </div><!-- inner -->
    </div><!-- outer -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is the behaviour you expected.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  widht: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}
.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.box .row.header {
  background: aliceblue;
}
.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: pink;
}
.box .row.content .title {
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.text {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}
.outer {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="title">
      <b>content</b>
      (fills remaining space)
    </div>

    <div class="outer">

      <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
        <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>

      </div>
      <!-- inner -->

    </div>
    <!-- outer -->


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm...closer, but I am looking for just the pink part to be scrollable. Also, could you point out specifically what change you made?

Comment: Ok updated the snippet at my answer. Please test it.

Comment: Looks like the new version does the trick. Boiled down, it looks like a flex-within-a-flex?

Comment: Yes. Flex nesting is usual.

Comment: I've added the nesting flexes to my real code and it looks to have fixed it. If you add some sort of explanation about that being necessary to your answer then I'll go ahead and accept it. As is, it's not immediately obvious what you changed to fix it, and I even wrote the original stylesheet.   :)

Answer (score 1):

The key to this layout is recognizing a flex item's *minimum size*:

> [**4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of
>   the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1.

In other words, a flex item will, by default, never be smaller than the size of its content.

*Initial settings on a flex item:*

```
min-width: auto;
min-height: auto;
```

This has the potential to force items to overflow their container.

The solution is to apply `min-width: 0` for horizontal scroll, and `min-height: 0` for vertical scroll, on the flex container.

Below is a simplified demonstration using your code (the JS is only to repeat the `.text` elements):

```js
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}

multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.text'), 10, true);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: aqua;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;              /* new */
    flex-direction: column;     /* new */   
    min-height: 0;              /* new; allow flex item to be smaller than its content,
                                   enabling scroll */
}

.outer {
    background-color: pink;
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.text {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
     <div class="header">header (sized to content, i.e., height: auto;)</div>
     <div class="content">content (fills remaining space, i.e. flex: 1;)
          <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner">
                   <div class="text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet tongue corned beef landjaeger sausage beef meatball, kielbasa pastrami turkey boudin hamburger ham hock chuck tail pork. Shankle tail cupim ribeye.</div>
                   </div><!-- inner -->
          </div><!-- outer -->
     </div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- box -->
```

Tested on Chrome, FF and IE11.

More information:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [Rendering problems using flexbox in Firefox and Chrome 48](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34982834/3597276)

Comment: I get your point, but if I remove the `min-height` from your snippet the layout still works, even on auto. Conversely, if I add the min-height to *my* version where the sub-elements of .content are normal divs it doesn't fix it,  until I make `.content` use its own flex layout. That seems to be the deciding factor in the height of the bottom pane.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest making `.content` a nested, column-direction flex container for this layout to work.